# Using 4-part naming to do insert to DB2 from SQL Server 2005?

Tags: sql-server-2005, odbc, db2

We're using DB2 9.1 on Linux and SQL Server 2005, and the IBM db2 odbc driver.  We have a linked server set up to DB2.  From SQL Server, I can do the following:

```
-- I can create the new table fine
exec ('create table dev.TestSylviaB (field1 int) in TS_DEV_USER_XXXX')
at LinkDB2

-- I can use 4 part naming to select from it, as long as I skip the second part and put everything in upper case
select * from LINKDB2..DEV.TESTSYLVIAB

-- I can insert using Exec (which does pass through)
exec ('insert into DEV.TestSylviaB (field1 ) values (1)') at LinkDB2

-- HOWEVER I cannot insert via the standard 4 part naming, like this:
insert into LINKDB2..DEV.TESTSYLVIAB values (1)
```

I get a "driver not capable" error message:

OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "LINKDB2" returned message "[IBM][CLI Driver] CLI0150E  Driver not capable. SQLSTATE=S1C00".
Msg 7343, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
The OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "LINKDB2" could not INSERT INTO table "[LINKDB2]..[DEV].[TESTSYLVIAB]".

Any thoughts?

thanks!
Sylvia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 4 part name insert is a distributed transaction and the DB2 driver needs to enroll into it. See [Registering the IBM DB2 Driver for ODBC and CLI with the Microsoft DTC](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.udb.apdv.cli.doc/doc/t0024165.htm).

Comment: Thank you Remus!  This looks good.  I can't actually test it right now but I'm very hopeful.  I will edit this when we actually get it to work.